# While loop used to work, now returns empty string

Tags: script, midi

I am following along a tutorial (http://autostatic.com/2013/10/20/using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-piano) on using the Rpi as a midi piano sampler, but the script is old and a while loop that used to work, hangs forever, as other readers have also commented.

```
while [ "$STATUS" != "100" ]
do
  STATUS=$(echo "GET CHANNEL INFO 0" | netcat -q 3 localhost 8888 \
| grep INSTRUMENT_STATUS | cut -d " " -f 2 | tr -d '\r\n')
done
```

I get no errors and I don't get any echo's, the script just hangs forever when it reaches these lines.

Can you tell me what could possibly be wrong? I don't understand the syntax with "|" so im kind of lost in to what the blocks between the "|" means, and how they combined should equal an int, so any explanation of this is very welcome.

Thanks for your time.
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just before the loop in the lines:

```
if ! pidof linuxsampler &> /dev/null
then
  linuxsampler --instruments-db-location $HOME/LinuxSampler/instruments.db \
&> /dev/null &
  sleep 5
netcat -q 3 localhost 8888 \
< $HOME/LinuxSampler/SalamanderGrandPianoV3.lscp &> /dev/null &
fi
```

I had to replace $HOME/ with /home/pi/

Now the $STATUS gets value 100